# use class methods for encapsulation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewdidload, class-members

i have made some @properties of uiimage view type in a class and then initialized that class in my rootviewcontroller.

questions.h:

```
@property(nonatomic,strong)UIImageView *img1;
@property(nonatomic,strong)UIImageView *img2;
@property(nonatomic,strong)UIImageView *img3;
@property(nonatomic,strong)UIImageView *img4;
```

'viewcontroller.m'

```
-(void)viewdidload{

questions *q1=[[questions alloc]init];
q1.img1 =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"red.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:q1.img1];


UITapGestureRecognizer *Tap1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(iTap:)];
[q1.img1 addGestureRecognizer:Tap1];

}


-(void)iTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
// do something..
}
```

i know its not a good idea to populate viewdidload with initialization code..
is there any better way to acive this using class methods ?

like :

questions.m:

```
+(questions * )mymethod{

questions *q1=[[questions alloc]init];
q1.img1 =[[uiimageview alloc]initwithimage [uimage imagenamed@"red.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:q1.img1];


UITapGestureRecognizer *Tap1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(iTap:)];
[q1.img1 addGestureRecognizer:Tap1];

return q1;
}
```

and then calling that method in viewdidload

viewcontroller.m:

```
-(void)viewdidload{

[questions mymethod];

}
```

Comment: You should first fix the most obvious errors in your code.

Comment: yes i know that ...please can answer my question in short

Comment: `initWithTarget:self` in class method will not work.

Comment: i previously tried giving "view controllers" instance in place of self ...but it was useless..

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing really wrong with creating adding views in `viewDidLoad`. You can however also use `- [UIViewController loadView]`.